# Non sequential list binding not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

As per this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) I am trying to bind a list of non sequential items.

View:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Products", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ %>
    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="cold" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Name" value="Beer" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Price" value="7.32" />
    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="123" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Name" value="Chips" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Price" value="2.23" />
    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="caliente" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Name" value="Salsa" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Price" value="1.23" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<%} %>
```

Action method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Products(IList<Product> products)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Binding doesn't seems to work for me, the parameter products always contains null. Am I missing something?

Any help much appreciated, Thanks.

Please note, I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Comment: You've spelled products wrong here: `<%using (Html.BeginForm("Producs", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`.  Have you just mistyped the code here or is your actual code looking like that too? Edit: Nevermind.  See what Darin posted.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Thats a typo, I would edit it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default model binder is capable of binding collections with non-sequential indexes starting from ASP.NET MVC 2.0. This is not supported in ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

Comment: Ok thanks Darin. Is there any other way I can achieve this in MVC 1.0?

Comment: @User123343, other than writing a custom model binder I don't see much possibilities. In fact upgrading to a more recent version would be the best solution IMHO. With the soon to be released ASP.NET 4.0 you will be 4 generations behind and accumulating more and more missing features.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot Darin for the help. Upgrading is currently in progress, so we will soon switch over to .net 4.0 :)