# ASP.NET Core using two models in single form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `Tuple` to pass two models inside the view like code given below.

```
@model Tuple<AdvanceSearchModel, List<SearchUserModel>>
<form role="search" method="post" action="/Public/AdvanceSearch">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input name="FullNames" type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Product</label>
                <input name="Products" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Location:</label>
                <input name="Location" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>State</label>
                <input name="States" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Country</label>
                <input name="Countries" type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

All the `name` attributes inside inputs are of `AdvanceSearchModel`. How do I use tag helper such as `asp-for` when passing multiple model to the views containing one or multiple forms? Also how do I retain values of the form after submitting the form in above scenario?

Comment: You cannot use a `Tuple` when editing data in a form - it will never bind to anything when you submit you form since a `Tuple` has no parameter-less constructor and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize it. Use a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code of InputTagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/f95d49c870fd00573592d576fa60ffb10435465b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs#L93)

You can see it creates the `name` attribute based on the (lambda) expression in html-tag:`asp-for`.

### what you need

You need a form `name` tag like this `SearchUserModel[0].Location`

Where:

- `SearchUserModel` is the property name on the model which is in the controller method you post to
- `[0]` is the index in the list
- `Location` is the property on the iten in the list the `SearchUserModel` instance

### My suggestion

### Not to do

1. Extend the InputTagHelper and add a prefix option (which adds a prefex to the name).
2. Use a view model Not a tuple!
3. Create a partial view that only takes `SearchUserModel` + a prefix (like an int for which row in the list it is for example: `usermodel[1]`)
4. In your view loop over the list and call the partial.

#### result

```
@model SearchUserModel
<input asp-for="Location" my-prefix="ListItem[@Model.Id]" class="form-control" />
```

## Better longterm option

1. Make a HTML template on how `SearchUserModel` part of the form should look.
2. Do ajax call to get the data or put the data as json in your view. (or take step 3 from what not to do)
3. Generate the form with well structured javascript.
4. On submit Instead of submitting the form, parse the from to json and send this as json ajax call.

Why do i say this? It is easier to debug if you get weird databindings in your controller.

That said, option 1 is perfectly fine but it might lead to problems later, as it is very static template, you wont be able to add or remove rows easily.

## References for proper html name tags for lists:

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx
- [How does MVC 4 List Model Binding work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822615/how-does-mvc-4-list-model-binding-work)

Comment: Thank you Joel for detailed answer. My second option was to use anularjs. Send form values trough API and get the results in JSON format and display it on the page using angularjs. For now I will stick to the angularjs option.