# Add model into model using Html helper HiddenFor C# MVC

Tags: c#, html, .net, model-view-controller, html-helper

I have a model like

```
public class Model
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public List<OtherModel> List { get; set; }
}

public class OtherModel
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsPropTrue { get; set; }
}
```

I am using `Model` in a View where I'm looping through the `List` to show data in a table.

Depending on whether one of the properties (`IsPropTrue`) in `OtherModel` is true or false, I want to use the `HiddenFor` Html helper and send the data to the `HttpPost` controller.

```
@model Model                                       
@foreach (var item in Model.List)
{                                          
    if (item.IsPropTrue)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=> item.Value1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=> item.Value2) 
    } 
}
```

I think it doesn't work because I should in some way add these properties to the `OtherModel`, which is inside the `Model`; But the way I have it now, I am adding properties to `Model`.

Comment: Ah yes, I made a mistake above :) Im doing @foreach (var item in Model.List)

Comment: I edited the question per OP's comment. It now shows the `foreach` iterating over `Model.List`.

Comment: Thank You, Lews :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
@model Model                                       
@foreach (var item in Model.List)
{                                          
    if (item.IsPropTrue)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.List[Model.List.IndexOf(item)].Value1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.List[Model.List.IndexOf(item)].Value2)
    } 
}
```

this way the binding system will bind the hidden fields with your List OtherModel in the Model

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, and it works, Thank You :)

Comment: It will not work if `item.IsPropTrue` if `false` in any iteration (you will generate non-consecutive indexers which will not bind)

Comment: so what to do in this case then?

Answer (score 0):

if you want send an array to server based on the Model you have to use indexer in @Html.HiddenFor .

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MyModel

<form>
    @if (Model != null && Model.List != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.List.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Model.List[i].IsPropTrue)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.List[i].Value1)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.List[i].Value2)
            }
        }
    }
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

if you want know reason of using indexer on model i recommend [How does MVC 4 List Model Binding work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822615/how-does-mvc-4-list-model-binding-work)

Answer (score 0):

Consider if it the responsibility of the view or the controller action to make the decisions - you can send everything back to the action to do the decision making.

In your Views/Shared folder, create a controller called EditorTemplates
In this folder, add a partial view called OtherModel
In this view, set the model to OtherModel and set the Layout=null
Add the three OtherModel fields in EditorFor (and HiddenFor if not displaying isPropTrue). This partial view displays just one instance of your list.

In your main view, use the above editor model like so. MVC will take care of all rendering and postback of the Model State for your complete list of items. We like one-liners...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherModel)
```

When the data is subsequently posted back to an action, Model State has wrapped up all of your displayed items into a list again, so you can check the isPropTrue value for each item on the server.

The only issue with MVC is that is you pass an empty list out to a view, you get a null value back, so just replace this with an empty list when null is returned